# Vulkan extent not resizing

Tags: vulkan

I have started a vulkan project using glfw and then realized that I can't use it, so I made my own windowing library, integrated it in my project and now every time I resize the window, minImageExtent and maxImageExtent from surface capabilities don't change, they are the original size that I created the window with. The windowing library can be found here: https://github.com/Sucuturdean/ntd/blob/master/ntd/window.h and if you need any code snipets from the actual code please say so in the comments.

Edit: I am developing on linux and the drivers work since I have tested with other applications.

Comment: Needs a MVCE. Nobody is gonna debug your whole codebase, and StackOverflow does not like external links. Make a minimal example. Limit yourself to one platform. Since it is just window it won't be that large code. Either you will figure it out in the process of making a MVCE, or you will end up with something that is digestible by the community that they can help you with.

Comment: PS: You should be checking return values. Notably from `PeekMessage`.

Comment: What does MVCE mean?

Comment: [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I was wondering if someone would know what could cause this error, not necessarily solve it.

Comment: The cause is clearly that it does not work. /s The driver likely just queries the window size from win32 API same as you would. So either the window is\was not resized (yet) caused by some mistake in your code, or in an off chance you have some very defective driver installed.

Comment: Like i said in the edit, I don't use win32 api, I use xcb

Comment: Alright. I think your problem is you are catching `XCB_RESIZE_REQUEST` (i.e. pre resize event) instead of `XCB_CONFIGURE_NOTIFY` (post resize event).